# Differential entropy is calculated with integrate.quad in scipy.stats?

Tags: python, entropy, continuous, information-theory, scipy.stats

`scipy.stats.entropy` calculates the **differential entropy** for a continuous random variable. By which estimation method, and which formula, exactly is it calculating differential entropy? (i.e. the differential entropy of a `norm` distribution versus that of the `beta` distribution)

Below is its github code. Differential entropy is the negative integral sum of the p.d.f. multiplied by the log p.d.f., but nowhere do I see this or the log written. Could it be in the call to `integrate.quad`?

```
def _entropy(self, *args):
    def integ(x):
        val = self._pdf(x, *args)
        return entr(val)

    # upper limit is often inf, so suppress warnings when integrating
    _a, _b = self._get_support(*args)
    with np.errstate(over='ignore'):
        h = integrate.quad(integ, _a, _b)[0]

    if not np.isnan(h):
        return h
    else:
        # try with different limits if integration problems
        low, upp = self.ppf([1e-10, 1. - 1e-10], *args)
        if np.isinf(_b):
            upper = upp
        else:
            upper = _b
        if np.isinf(_a):
            lower = low
        else:
            lower = _a
        return integrate.quad(integ, lower, upper)[0]
```

Source (lines 2501 - 2524): https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py

Comment: I think this is the actual function using differential entropy.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.differential_entropy.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a continuous random variable in some parametrized way anyway, unless you work with an approximation.  In that case, you usually work with distribution objects; and for known distributions, formulae for the differential entropy in terms of the parameters exist.

Scipy accordingly provides an [`entropy` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.entropy.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.entropy) for `rv_continuous` that calculates the differential entropy where possible:

```
In [5]: import scipy.stats as st                                                                                                                             

In [6]: rv = st.beta(0.5, 0.5)                                                                                                                               

In [7]: rv.entropy()                                                                                                                                         
Out[7]: array(-0.24156448)
```

Comment: rv_continuous.entropy only returns True or False and not a value for differential entropy. what does this mean?

Comment: What? That's not what it's supposed to do, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1135-L1169). Are you sure you're calling it correctly?

Comment: even the example in your link shows a Boolean returned output: >>> drv = rv_discrete(values=((0, 1), (0.5, 0.5)))        >>> np.allclose(drv.entropy(), np.log(2.0))
        **True**

Comment: Yeah, sure. As a result of a call to `np.allclose`. Which shows that the result of `entropy` is approximately equal to `log(2)`, _an irrational number_.

Comment: so you're saying rv_continuous.entropy is normally supposed to give back a real number for an output and not a Boolean? please show an example without np.allclose that works

Comment: It sure should, according to both the docs and the source code I linked to. I can't produce an example myself, as I'm on my phone; why don't you just try it?

Comment: I did try before all this, and it gives an error i think because i don't know how to discretize a continuous r.v.. That's why i thought the np.allclose does the discretizing but now i'm told that even that is causing the current Boolean thing

Comment: I don't quite get what you try to do. There's no need to discretize if you can represent the continuous distribution in parametrized form. See my edit.

Comment: ok, I've figured out the Boolean issue and am getting a numerical entropy value now. But how is `.entropy` actually calculating it for these families of distributions? what formula and estimation method for entropy is the function using?

Answer (score 0):

The actual question here is how do you store a continuous variable in memory. You might use some discretization techniques and calculate entropy for a discrete random variable.

You also may check [Tensorflow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Distribution), which treats distributions essentially as tensors and has a method `entropy()` for a `Distribution` class.

Comment: do u mean discretize the continuous random variable array using scipy.stats.rv_discrete? How is this done for a T-sized vector/time series? The docs only show an example of a uniform binary variable